# How do I” Pass variable between .phtml files?

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, variables

I have a variable in `item.phtml` file  (order approval extension) in my base folder and I want to pass It to another `.phtml` file (one called `cart.phtml`). I don’t think `cart.phtml` is a child of `item.phtml`. The variable is called `$postdata` and is just a simple PHP variable and I wish to display the text is holds on the same page as `item.phtml` but in another file.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know why you want to do this But you can use Magento `registry` for this.

Set data to registry

```
Mage::register('name-of-registry-key', $postdata);
```

Get your data

```
$var = Mage::registry('name-of-registry-key');
```

Clear registry data

```
Mage::unregister('name-of-registry-key');
```